# Ruby on rails comment on post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a model to add comments to a post. I have no error message when I run the sever but when I click on the "submit" button after filling the text box, nothing happen. It does not create the comment (and no error message). Now I am stuck. Could have look in my program and tell me if coded something wrong?
Thanks a lot for your support

***comments_controller.rb***

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
      @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
      @comment= @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))

     if @comment.save
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
     else
        render 'new'
     end
   end
end
```

***comments/_form.html.erb***

```
<%= simple_form_for [@post, @post.comments.build] do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :comment %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

***posts/show.html.erb***

```
<h1><%= @post.title %></h1>
<p><%= @post.content %></p>

<h3> Reply to thread </h3>
<%= render "comments/form" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not rendering the comments in `show.html.erb`, maybe add something like this:

```
<h3>Comments</h3>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%= comment.comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

Also it's very confusing to have a `comment` field for the `Comment` model, maybe change it to `content` or something more meaningful.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Even if I render the comment in the code, it still does not work.

Comment: @Antoine please replace `create` with `create!` and tell us if it errors or not.

Answer (score 0):

Also one thing I can add to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46021779/5872935) is the `create` method will automatically save the new model so no need to run `.save` again i think it would be better to put it like

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])

    if @post.comments.create(params[:comment].permit(:comment))
      redirect_to post_path(@post)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

*Or maybe keep as it is in your question and use `.build` instead of `.create`*

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I use the `.build` and the `.save` in the `if` for another model in which it works. I wondering if this time it is not the '[@post, @post.comments.build]' that could be wrong.

Comment: `[@post, @post.comments.build]` looks good to me simple form would have failed if it was wrong. Other alternative is define `@comment=@post.comments.build` in the `new` method inside the controller but it works both ways

Comment: You can always check in the `rails console` if the build was successful by checking the last comment created on that post and make sure you permit the write key from the params _i usually use `params.require(:comment).permit(:comment)` which IMH is more ruby

Comment: I just tried both to change `.create` in `.build` and check in the console. I still don't get the comment saved.

Comment: Try using `create!` to see what are the errors e.g: `if @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comment))`

Comment: I got the following error message `Validation failed: User must exist`

Comment: Looks like your `comment` validation require a `user_id` so if your application supports a `current_user` method try `if @post.comments.create!(params.require(:comment).permit(:comm‌​ent).merge(user: current_user))`